# Embedded System: Which platform or board?

Tags: audio, embedded-linux, embedded

I want to build a portable system / device for processing guitar effects (own pod)

I need:
touchscreen (as main input)
ssd / sd card or other?
intel pentium i3,5,7? (needs power for processing realtime effects
network (bluetooth, wlan, ethernet ...) (for control, configuration ...)
audio input / output (for the guitar / recording ...)
linux
transportable (no big power supply, with rechargeable batteries and also usb and normal power supply)

i would write the application running on the system with c++ in qt

I saw many interesting boards like arduino, beagleboard, hawkboard and some mini / micro itx embedded systems, but now i dont know anymore which one i should choose

should also be easy to develope for and not so expensive

Comment: i develope the software in qt (c++) and it is planned as a guitar pod (effects), currently i just want to know which is the best platform or are the best platforms with the wished features above i could use. so its currently for testing, the devleopement is done on my latop in qt (c++) currently

Comment: but i want to do this with qt (c++) so the software should do this. i understand you but i want to do this with c++ in qt on an embedded system

Comment: Well great, has someone a good answer for me as beginner? Already working on the QT Version (C++), so I want to get a good platform for it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I want to run a QT App for processing guitar effects (the qt application does all this!) on an embedded system (should be linux?) i already searched for this but found nothing good solution (most what i found was some years old?)

Comment: Mh, but i use some sound apis for doing all this for me in c++ with qt. So shouldnt it work with that?

Comment: so should i give up? =( already worked with assembler and c, java and so on but with this project i need a lot of help =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an **[Arduino project](http://www.instructables.com/id/Lo-fi-Arduino-Guitar-Pedal/)** doing that. Take a look. If you need more power then you will need something like ARM or some DSP microcontroller.

Comment: I have bumped into another one, also AVR based: http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/FinalProjects/s2011/afj8_pp332/index.html

Comment: And yet another one: http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/FinalProjects/s2011/bmc68_mjk277/bmc68_mjk277/index.html

Comment: -1 Arduino lacks the ability to handle reasonable audio quality, and will definetely not run QT.